# Generic enum type in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, enums

I have two objective-c classes `HondaDealerShip` and `FordDealerShip`. They both contain similar properties and methods, so I want to define a common protocol `DealerShip` and do some polymorphism.

The problem is this `DealerShip` needs to contain generic enum type properties, so that `HondaDealerShip` and `FordDealerShip` can have different `concrete` enum types.

So I want something like this,

```
@protocol DealerShip 

@property (nonatomic, readonly) enum location;

-(void)printPriceOfModel:(enum)vehicleModel;

@end
```

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, HondaLocation) {
     HondaLocationSouthEast,
     HondaLocationNorthWest
}

typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, HondaModel) {
     Accord,
     Civic
}

@interface HondaDealerShip: NSObject<DealerShip>

@property (nonatomic, readonly) HondaLocation location;

- (void)printPriceOfModel:(HondaModel)vehicleModel {
     //print price here
}

@end
```

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, FordLocation) {
     FordLocationEast,
     FordLocationWest
}

typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, FordModel) {
     Mustang,
     Focus
}

@interface FordDealerShip: NSObject<DealerShip>

@property (nonatomic, readonly) FordLocation location;

- (void)printPriceOfModel:(FordModel)vehicleModel {
     //print price here
}

@end
```

If I have to do this in `swift`, I could use protocols with associated types like below

```
protocol DealerShip {
    associatedtype Location
    associatedtype Model

    var location: Location { get }
    func printPriceOfModel(model : Model)
}

enum HondaLocation: Int {
    case sountEast
    case northWest
}

enum HondaModel: Int {
    case accord
    case civic
}

struct HondaDealerShip: DealerShip {
    var location: HondaLocation
    func printPriceOfModel(model: HondaModel) {
        //print
    }
}

//same for FordDealerShip
```

can I do similar in objective-c?.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you cannot use enum with associated types in objective c. The language does not support it.